# Watermarking by key in Spark structured streaming

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I have data coming in on Kafka from IoT devices. The timestamps of the sensor data of these devices are often not in sync due to network congestion, device being out of range, etc.

We have to write streaming jobs to aggregate sensor values over a window of time for each device independently. With the groupby with watermark operation, we lose the data of all devices that lag behind device with latest timestamp.

Is there any way that the watermarks could be applied separately to each device based on the latest timestamp for that device, and not the latest timestamp across all devices?

We cannot keep a large lag as the device could be out of range for days. We cannot run an individual query for each device as the number of devices is high.

Would it be achievable using flatMapGroupsWithState? Or is this something that cannot be achieved with Spark Structured Streaming at all?

Answer (score 3):

I think instead of watermarking by event timestamp (which could be lagging behind as you said), you could apply a watermark over the processing timestamp (i.e. the time when you process the data in your Spark job). I faced a very similar problem in a recent project I was working on and that's how I solved it.

Example:

```scala
val dfWithWatermark = df
  .withColumn("processingTimestamp", current_timestamp())
  .withWatermark("processingTimestamp", "1 day")

// ... use dfWithWatermark to do aggregations etc
```

This will keep a state over 1 day of your IoT data, no matter what the timestamp of the data is that you're receiving.

There are some limitations to this of course, for example if there are devices that send data in intervals larger than your watermark. But to figure out a solution for this you'd have to be more specific with your requirements.

By using `flatMapGroupsWithState` you can be *very* specific with your state keeping, but I don't think it's really necessary in your case.

Edit: if you however decide to go with `flatMapGroupsWithState`, you can use different timeouts per device group by calling `state.setTimeoutDuration()` with different intervals, depending on the type of device you process. This way you can be very specific with the state keeping.

Comment: you can use different timestamps in aggregations and watermarks

Comment: Thank you for your response.

1. Many of my use cases involve looking at patterns in a sliding window. If i receive data after the processing time based watermark times out, i lose data from multiple sliding windows.

2. My devices can be in the wilderness for multiple days so we its difficult to get optimum watermark duration.

3. Another argument against a large watermark is the amount of data 
(1000 devices * 300 parameters + metadata) per second

With flatMapGroupsWithState can we have separate watermarks for each group? i couldn't find any clarity on this online.

Comment: Yes, with flatMapGroupsWithState you can have different timeouts per group. You can simply set `state.setTimeoutDuration("1 day")` for one of your devices and `state.setTimeoutDuration("1 week")` for another one of your devices. Based on the device information you would have to decide how long to wait until you time out

Comment: @hbrgnr But this state timeout is something completely else than watermark. It is just timeout of the state. But is is up to you what you will put to it. Watermarking is about sorting out of order elements. This is about expiration of the state if it is not touched for some time.